# how can I convert these outputted coordinates to standard looking ones?

Tags: python-3.x, converters, implicit-conversion, coordinate-systems

I have this code that outputs coordinates for a port:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request as request
import re



a = input("What country is your port in?: ")
b = input("What is the name of the port?: ")

url = "http://ports.com/"
country = ["united-kingdom","greece"]
ports = ["port-of-eleusis","portsmouth-continental-ferry-port","poole-harbour"]

totalurl = "http://ports.com/" + a + "/" + b + "/"
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(totalurl)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<strong>Coordinates:</strong>(.*?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

with urllib.request.urlopen(totalurl) as response:
    html = htmltext.decode()

num = re.findall(pattern, html)
print(num)
```

The output is correct and readable but I need the coordinates to something like this format: 39°09'24.6''N 175°37'55.8''W instead of :

```
>>> [' 50&deg;48&prime;41.04&Prime;N 1&deg;5&prime;31.31&Prime;W']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused because HTML internally uses these codes to display specific unicode characters, while python does not. To fix this, replace `print(num)` with `print(list(i.replace('&deg;', "°").replace('&prime;',"′").replace('&Prime;',"″") for i in num))`

This essentially replaces `&deg;` with `°`, `&prime;` with `′`, and `&Prime;` with `″`.

```
>>> print(list(i.replace('&deg;', "°").replace('&prime;',"′").replace('&Prime;',"″") for i in num))
[" 50°48′41.04″N 1°5′31.31″W"]
>>>
```